# Producing negative to positive square wave pulse

Tags: mosfet, pwm, switching

Situation

- I need 2 kHz -10/40 V square wave duty <1 % pulse to drive 50 ohm load.
- I have a working 0-40 V solution: PWM by MCU driving a N-MOSFET low side switch off a 40 V DC rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4VbuX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Questions:

- Is it possible to somewhat shift the voltage to negative after MOSFET output (low side is tricky, no common ground)?
- If not, what is the most practical way to produce such pulse?

Comment: Transformer if you can find a suitable one.

Comment: If you need low to be -10 volts irrespective of changes in duty cycle then you need a negative rail or circa 12 volts. Create one or make one or redefine 0 volts as -10 volts.

Comment: If you don't have a -10 V supply, you can use a zener clamp with a DC restorer starting with a 50V supply. using very low ESR RdsOn parts https://tinyurl.com/y2rvywy6

Comment: @Andyaka Could you please show me how to use the negative rail ? If I insert negative rail to high side, L will be short. If I insert negative to low side, MCU will be burnt.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is by using a differentiator(op-amp circuit).[This](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_7.html) website provides the basics.